# GEE does not recognize strings when labeling a chart in ui.Chart.image.regions

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

I'm trying to create a chart en GEE, with labels for each series.
GEE does not recognize strings when labeling a chart in ui.Chart.image.regions

The error is

```
Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string
```

Link to the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/8b7e15d104bf8a996f0e964e980f67ff

and part of the code:

```
Map.setOptions('satellite')

print(temps)

Map.centerObject(puntos)
print('puntos',puntos)
print('parcela',puntos.first().get('Parcela'))

Map.addLayer(temps.select('t01'), {min:0, max:30, palette:['blue','green','orange','red']},
    'Temperatura enero',0);

Map.addLayer(puntos,{},'puntos Lacar')

var areas = puntos.map(function(f){
  var f2 = f.buffer(5)
  return f2
})

print('areas',areas)

var chartT =
    ui.Chart.image.regions({
          image: temps,
          regions: areas,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 5,
          //seriesProperty: 'label',
          //xProperty:'Parcela'
    })
          //.setChartType('ColumnChart');

print(chartT);

var tempsEnPuntos = temps.reduceRegions({
  collection:puntos,
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale:5})
  
print(tempsEnPuntos,'tempEnPuntos')

// Export the FeatureCollection to a KML file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: tempsEnPuntos,
  description:'tempsEnPuntosLacar',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

This is an example of the result I'm looking for, but I need each series named with the name of the Site:

[image: This is an example of the result I'm looking for, but I need each series named with the name of the Site:]

Comment: What are you trying to visualize? Please describe more about your data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm trying to visualize the image i've just added